# jQuery Sortable/Draggable list disableselection() not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using [HTML5 Sortable](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/) for Sortable and Draggable list.

**Issue**

I am using jQuery `disableSelection()` for disabling list moving from right to left. That is not working. is there any other way to avoid list moving from right to left.

**HTML**

```
<section>
        <h1>Sortable Lists</h1>
        <ul id="sortable1" class="connected sortable list">
            <li draggable="true">Item 1
            </li><li draggable="true">Item 3
            </li><li draggable="true" class="" style="display: list-item;">Item 2
            </li><li draggable="true">Item 4
            </li><li draggable="true">Item 5
            </li><li draggable="true">Item 6
        </li></ul>
        <ul id="sortable2" class="connected sortable list">
            <li class="highlight" draggable="true">Item 1
            </li><li class="highlight" draggable="true" style="display: list-item;">Item 2
            </li><li class="highlight" draggable="true">Item 3
            </li><li class="highlight" draggable="true">Item 4
            </li><li class="highlight" draggable="true">Item 5
            </li><li class="highlight" draggable="true">Item 6
        </li></ul>
    </section>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
       $(".connected").sortable({
           connectWith: ".connected"
        }).disableSelection();
});
```

**Fiddle**

I have put the code in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeysinghanbu/uxv309Lb/4/)

Comment: You can't with this poor plugin, you should use that : http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `#id` instead of `.ClassName` add one more `disableSelection()` method for Partiular `#id`

```
 $(function () {

   $("#sortable1").sortable({
       connectWith: "#sortable2"
    }).disableSelection();

    $("#sortable2").sortable({
    }).disableSelection();

});
```

Updated [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uxv309Lb/8/)